# Jquery Hide parent div onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to hide parent div when a child div is clicked.I have appended the div when "add more" button is clicked.In short when "X" in div is clicked its parent div should hide.Here is my [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/abinaya91/V4Xgq/1/)

```
$( "#appenddiv" ).on( "click", function() {
     $( ".uploadimg" ).append( "<div class='image'><div class='delete'>X</div></div>" );
});
$(".delete").on("click",function(){
    $(this).parent().hide();
});
```

Comment: delegation is the keyword you are looking for

Comment: And you can be selective too: `$(this).closest(".image").hide()`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason why your code not working is, That element is being appended in to the DOM dynamically, so we have to use [**`event delegation`**](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) to make the code work..

Try,

```
$(".uploadimg").on("click",".delete",function(){
    $(this).parent().hide();
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/V4Xgq/3/)

Answer (score 3):

You need event delegation for dynamically generated DOM:

```
  $("body").on("click",'.delete',function(){
   $(this).parent().hide();
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/V4Xgq/2/)**

Answer (score 3):

you should use deligates for dynamically created items

```
 $(document).on("click",".delete" function () {
        $(this).parent().hide();
    });
```